# nhamcs design on survey package (R)

Tags: programming, survey

I am trying to analyze nhamcs http://www.nber.org/data/national-hospital-ambulatory-medical-care-survey.html using Lumley's survey package but getting the wrong standard errors when comparing them against http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/ahcd/nhamcs_emergency/2011_ed_web_tables.pdf

current design object is defined as:

> data.design <- survey::svydesign(id = ~CPSUM, strata = ~CSTRATM, 
>      weight = ~PATWT, data = data, nest = TRUE)

but this gives me the wrong s.e. for example, for the total population number of visits I get:

> ```
>     total      SE
> ```
>
> [1,] 136296400 7370965

while the pdf above reports (in thousands for both totals and s.e.):

> 136,296 (6,413)

would appreciate any thoughts on where I might be going wrong

Comment: hi, the docs say the PUF cluster and strata are masked.  ask cdc if those tables you are trying to match were generated using an internal file (with more detailed cluster & strata) or if they were generated using the public file?  ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Dataset_Documentation/NHAMCS/doc2010.pdf#page=116